# HTML + CSS: How can I achieve the expected behaviour (without JS!)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Please help me with this responsive design.

This is my HTML layout:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="images">
                <div id="cats">
                    <img src="cat-image-1.png" />
                    <img src="cat-image-2.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="dogs" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="dog-image-1.png" />
                    <img src="dog-image-2.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="chat_wrapper">
                <div id="chat_messages">
                    Chat messages in here
                </div>
                <div id="chat_input">
                    <input type="text" value="Type to chat" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now let me explain what the CSS should do:

There is a div #images and a div #chat_wrapper in #wrapper.

The divs #cats and #dogs in #images have an unknown number of images in them (= height is unknown).

The #chat_wrapper should always try to fill the entire screen, but if the div #cats or #dogs is visible the #chat_wrapper should collapse to avoid the document element to have a height greater than window height. (min-height should be at least 400px, so if let's say #dogs fills 100% of the window height, you should be able to scroll down to the chat.

I don't known if it's possible with CSS only, can you help? :)

Thanks a lot!

Screenshot #1:

[image]

**#dogs is visible, the #chat_wrapper fills the rest of the remaining space, you just can scroll the #chat_messages div (the #chat_input doesn't move)**

Screenshot #2:

[image]

**Just chat is visible, you just can scroll the #chat_messages div (the #chat_input doesn't move)**

Screenshot #3:

[image]

**#dogs is visible with some images, you can scroll the entire window, the chat is 400px high, you can scroll the #chat_messages div (the #chat_input just moves if you scroll the entire window)**

Comment: A diagram would help.

Comment: Can you include your CSS so far, too. As a jsFiddle would be nice.

Comment: Your description makes not really sense. On one hand you write if #dogs is visible the chat should collapse to keep the document height withing the screen height. On the other hand you talk about scrolling to the chat when #dogs fills the screen.

Comment: I will upload some screenshots. :)

Comment: Added 3 screenshots. Was not able to add "http://" to the last one (more than 2 links need a reputation of more than 10 which I don't have yet)

Comment: @Leon What you are asking is not clear.  Post CSS and write something like question: How can I X.

Comment: It's not easy to write a question as the question is very complicated. I will add CSS soon.

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/ebohoc This one uses JavaScript, but I search a CSS only solution. Try to toggle display: none on the cats and the dogs div and see how it should look like

Answer (score 0):

I edited the 3rd link to add http://.

The #dogs div could be scrollable.
Fix a max-height to the div and use the overflow property to make it scrollable.

---

As described here : [Mozilla Developer Network - overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

> div   {
>   width:150px;
>   height:150px;
>   overflow:scroll;
>   }

**Note : Note: The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit".**

---

If you don't want a scrollable #dogs div, then use display: block for img

---

Try :

```
img {
    display: block;
}

#chat_input {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    witdh: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

And fix a max-height for the message-container if you want to.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I want. It's not that easy. The #dogs div is not scrollable. Just the entire window and the chat_messages div is scrollable.

Comment: display block for img ?

@raam86 : The problem of MDN, is that it's only for mozilla.

Comment: Please see the comments on my question, I added my code to JSBin so it's easier to understand :)

Comment: @Done it is not. MDN shows the specification. If something mozilla-specific is listed on MDN, it is clearly marked as non-standard. If something is not supported everywhere, the browser support table as well as a polyfill (in case of javascript functions) is present.